# MI BOTON DE GUARDAR NO SE EJECUTA CORRECTAMENTE

Tags: javascript, php, crud

1.Hola ue tal, disculpen, me podrian ayudar en con mi codigo.
Al estar ejecutandolo me sale ue mi id esta indefinido pero no se como resolver eso. El problema esta en la parte de la funcion de modificarRegistro, la cual parece no estar recibiendo el id y no se cual sea el motivo.Sucede cuando presiono el boton guardar cambios, me sale mi alerta de id indefinida y luego otra donde me dice ke la id es indefinida pero me muestra los datos ke keria modificar, llevo 6 hora intentando y nada.Soy estudiante de programacion web.
este es mi codigo principal:

```
<?php require_once "encabezado.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>



    <script>
    $(function() {
        refresca();

        function limpia() {
            n = $("#jsTabla tr").length;
            for (i = n - 2; i > 0; i--) {
                $("#jsTabla tbody tr:eq('" + i + "')").remove();
            }
        }

        function refresca() {
            limpia();
            $.getJSON("refrecacarrusel.php", {}, function(datos) {
                alert("Actualizando");
                for (x = 0; x < datos.length; x++) {
                    $("#jsTabla tr:last").after('<tr><td>' + datos[x]['id'] + '</td><td>' + datos[x][
                        'imagen'
                    ] + '</td><td>' + datos[x]['alternativo'] + '</td><td>' + datos[x][
                        'estatus'
                    ] + '</td></tr>');
                    $("#jsTabla td:last").after('<td><button class="btn btn-eliminar" data-id="' +
                        datos[x]['id'] +
                        '"> <img class="img-fluid" src="Imagenes/trash.svg"></button></td>');

                    $("#jsTabla td:last").after('<td><button class="btn btn-editar" data-id="' + datos[
                            x]['id'] +
                        '"> <img class="img-fluid" src="Imagenes/pencil.svg"></button></td>');

                }
            });
        }

        alert("Consulta  tu carrusel de imagenes UwU");

        $("#limpiar").on("click", function() {

            $("#id").val("");
            $("#imagen").val("");
            $("#alternativo").val("");
            $("#estatus").val("");




        });
        $("#grabar").on("click", function() {

            alert("Momento de grabar su dato :)");
            var img = $("#imagen").val();
            var alter = $("#alternativo").val();
            $.getJSON("grabargaleria.php", {
                img: img,
                alter: alter
            }, function(datos) {
                alert("Espere un momento...");
                if (datos == "si") {
                    alert("Dato registrado perfectamente");
                    refresca();

                }
            });

        });


        function eliminarRegistro(id) {
            $.getJSON("eliminargaleria.php", {
                id: id
            }, function(datos) {
                if (datos == "si") {
                    alert("Se eliminó el registro con éxito");
                    refresca();
                } else {
                    alert("Error al intentar eliminar el registro");
                }
            });
        }

        $("#jsTabla").on("click", ".btn-eliminar", function() {
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            eliminarRegistro(id);
        });

        $("#jsTabla").on("click", ".btn-editar", function() {
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            alert("ID obtenido: " + id);


            var imagen = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
            var alternativo = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
            var estatus = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text();

            $("#imagen").val(imagen);
            $("#alternativo").val(alternativo);
            $("#estatus").val(estatus);

            $("#guardarCambios").show();
            $("#estatus").show();
            $("label").show();

        });
        
        function modificarRegistro(id) {
            alert(id);
            var img = $("#imagen").val();
            var alter = $("#alternativo").val();
            var esta = $("#estatus").val();

            alert("Modificando registro con id: " + id + ", imagen: " + img + ", alternativo: " + alter +
                ", estatus: " + esta);

            $.getJSON("modificargaleria.php", {
                id: id,
                img: img,
                alter: alter,
                estatus: esta
            }, function(datos) {
                if (datos == "si") {
                    alert("Se modificó el registro con éxito");
                    refresca();
                } else {
                    alert("Error al intentar modificar el registro");
                }
            });
        }

        $("#guardarCambios").click(function() {
                
                var id = $("#id").val();
                modificarRegistro(id);
            

        });
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <br><br>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <table id="jsTabla" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> id </th>
                            <th> imagen </th>
                            <th> alternativo </th>
                            <th> estatus </th>
                            <th> borrar </th>
                            <th> modificar </th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <h1>Consulta tu carrusel</h1>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label>
                                    Imagen
                                </label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="imagen" placeholder="Imagen...">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label>
                                    Texto alternativo:
                                </label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="alternativo" placeholder="Texto alternativo...">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label id="label" style="display:none;">
                                    Estatus:
                                </label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="estatus" placeholder="Estatus..." style="display:none;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="guardarCambios" value="Guardar Cambios" style="display:none;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="grabar" value="Grabar">

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="limpiar" value="Limpiar">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

y este es mi codigo de modificargaleria.php:

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $img = $_GET['img'];
  $alter = $_GET['alter'];
  $estatus = $_GET['estatus'];

  require_once "Servidor_Base.php";

  $llama = new ServidorBase("proyecto", "root", "");
  $con = $llama->Conexion();

  $sql = $con->prepare("UPDATE carrusel SET imagen = :a, alternativo = :b, estatus =:c WHERE id = :id");
  $sql->bindParam(':id', $id);
  $sql->bindParam(':a', $img);
  $sql->bindParam(':b', $alter);
  $sql->bindParam(':c', $estatus);


  $ok = "no";
  if ($sql->execute()) {
      $ok = "si";
  }
  $sql->closeCursor();
  echo json_encode($ok);
  ?>
```

adjunto capturas de lo ke sale cuando le doy clic al boton guardar cambios:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

en tu formulario, viste que debes mandar la id o un box o algo que tenga el nombre de id un ejemplo seria id='id' lo cual busca tu GET, pero como no lo tenes, no lo envía por eso te sale el error de vacío
$id = $_GET['id'];

Comment: Pregunta, si tomas el primer registro de la tabla te muestra el id pero si tomas del segundo en adelanta te muestra un id indefinido?